# Index was outside the bounds of the array - RichTextBox lines setvalue

Tags: insert, indexing, richtextbox, delphi-prism

I've searched online and on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to find the answer to my question, although some of them came very close.

I am programming for .Net in Delphi Prism. I have a RichTextBox on a WinForm and I need to insert a line of text at the top every time program does insert. So, I am doing the following and it runs upto the line and raises the following exception.

offending code:

```
RichTextBox1.Lines.SetValue(str,0);
```

Exception:
**Index was outside the bounds of the array**

I think, I think I know why it is raising the exception. It's because there are no lines inserted into RichTextBox. So, my program really can't insert any line of text. I need to really insert line of text at the top everytime my program inserts a new line of text.

If I do call RichTextBox1.AppendText(str);, then it works and inserts the str text without newline, but it appends at the end. I want it inserting text at the top every time.

How do you insert line of text into RichTextBox?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a .Insert(string,int) method or something similar? .SetValue() sounds like a method that replaces a line, not inserts one.

Comment: @Charles, I did see an insert function RichTextBox, but I can't find it now. I know, it wasn't for the lines though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lines property of the textbox is simply an array of string. So you need to add one element, move all elements one index down and insert your new text at the first index.

Also the Text property of the textbox is a string. Strings in .NET are immutable, so you need to fully replace the value.

One approach would be like this:

```
RichTextBox1.Text := "YourNewText" + Environment.NewLine + RichTextBox1.Text;
```

Comment: I think your approach is simple and works. I could spend some more time researching into this, but I would only waste time. Thank you.